# How to flatten array and preserve keys?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I have this simple array:

```
[
    'key1' => 'value',
    'key2' => 'value',
    'key3' => [
        'u-key1' => 'value',
        'u-key2' => 'value'
    ]
]
```

I want to flatten it into this form:

```
[
    'key1' => 'value',
    'key2' => 'value',
    'u-key1' => 'value',
    'u-key2' => 'value'
]
```

I'm sure there's a simple way of doing it with Collection/Arr helpers in Laravel, but can't figure it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41865104/flatten-array-while-preserving-key-value-pairs-in-php check here

Answer (score 0):

try like this one:
your array:

```
$arr= [
    'key1' => 'value',
    'key2' => 'value',
    'key3' => [
         'u-key1' => 'value',
         'u-key2' => 'value'
     ]
]
```

your function :

```
$data = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr));
foreach($data as $index=> $d) {
   $r[$index]=$d;
}
 print_r($r);
```

for more details go here https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$data = [
    'key1' => 'value',
    'key2' => 'value',
    'key3' => [
        'u-key1' => 'value',
        'u-key2' => 'value'
    ]
];

$array = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($data));

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $result[$key] = $value;
}

print_r($result);
```

*OUTPUT :*

```
Array
(
    [key1] => value
    [key2] => value
    [u-key1] => value
    [u-key2] => value
)
```

**Your question's answer DEMO below**

https://paiza.io/projects/F7G_b_S_skT916OeBrl2xw